# How can I make a Flutter application that is connected to Google Sheets that updates every time a cell is edited?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, arduino

I am currently making a monitoring application that integrates Arduino to an application, and I am using Google Sheets as the data transfer medium. Arduino > GSheets > App. Say I want to be able to update the displayed temperature on the app based on the latest logged temperature on the GSheet. Can this process be done without needing to restart the app? My current code needs a restart to see cell updates in the app. I am using Flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title:

- When the app is initially loaded, you need to store the initial value of Gsheet cell in shared preferences.
- Then create a periodic function that (Timer class of async library) makes a request to the Gsheets. The result of the request should have the last cell edited.
- Access the cell you stored previously in shared preferences and compare it with the result from the Gsheets periodic function. If there is a difference, update the UI & update shared preferences.

Periodic function sample:

```
// Using provider

class Subscriptionsprovider with ChangeNotifier {
  var _newValue;
 
  dynamic get newValue => _newValue;

  Timer? _timer;

  subscriptionsUpdate() {
    const sec = Duration(seconds: 1); // manage the timing properly
    _timer = Timer.periodic(sec, (Timer t) async {
     var gValue =  await _checkGsheets();
     var sValue =  await _checkSharedPrefs();
     if(gValue != sValue){
      // for the UI
      _newValue = gValue;
       notifyListeners();
       await_updateSharedPrefernces(_newValue);
       }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer!.cancel();
  }
}
```

To bring to the UI:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<Subscriptionsprovider>().subscriptionsUpdate();
  }

....

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final subscriptionProvider = context.watch<Subscriptionsprovider>();

return Container(child:Text(subscriptionProvider.newValue));
....
```

**Important**: Remember to setup your provider properly. If you don't understand how providers work, you need to do more research.